If I was knocked approximately 1500 feet into the air and I can fly, could I perform a sort of 'Terminal Velocity Tackle'?
And if I could, how much damage would I - and the target - take? Could a Terminal Velocity Tackle actually be viable against a BBEG, if the circumstances allow it to happen in the first place?
Now, when I say 'Terminal Velocity Tackle', I am referring to diving until I get close enough to the ground (reaching terminal velocity in the process), pulling up with my wings to transfer my downward momentum into horizontal momentum, and slamming my body into the target while staying as close to my falling speed of 500 feet per round as I can, thus tackling them at terminal velocity.

@Mary does the edited version appear to have enough details on what exactly I'm trying to accomplish?

How are you going to be knocked 1500 feet into the air?  That sounds a bit painful.

@Jack - Indeed, real-world physics suggests that, to a decent approximation, it should hurt about as much to be given a kick that gets one to a certain height as to fall from that same height and hit the ground. If I were the DM, I would certainly assess at least 20d6 damage both when they were launched into the air and when they hit the ground. Good luck surviving that, especially if you have already taken damage, unless you are a level 20 barbarian.

Maybe some sort of fairy launcher.  A ballista.  Or maybe a giant spring.  Or a rocket . . . .

@Obie2.0 This sounds like a good answer already. It just needs the page on where to find the info on falling damage and a link to other questions about falling onto others. :)

@Tasi I'm beginning to think we may need a kamikaze tag for some of your questions! ;)

I would just consider that momentum as a concept doesn't exist within the rules.  Which is why when you fall, it is instantaneous.  When your turn ends, even if you are running, you stop.

Yes, sort of (with the optional rule for falling onto creatures)
Tasha's Cauldron of Everything includes an optional rule for falling onto another creature. I won't quote it in full here, since TCE is not a freely available source, but the basic idea is that the creature gets a chance to dodge you, and if it fails, the fall damage is split between it and you. The standard rules for falling say that the maximum falling damage is 20d6 (representing an impact at terminal velocity), which results from falling from at least 200 feet. So, if your suggested maneuver is successful, you and the BBEG would each take approximately 10d6 damage (technically you should roll 20d6 and divide by 2, but close enough). So, if you are willing to take that much damage yourself in order to damage the BBEG, then this plan may well be worth it. But keep in mind that the BBEG still has a chance to dodge your human(oid) missile, in which case the full 20d6 damage goes to you.
One potentially important technicality is that in terms of the mechanics, you can't exactly "pull out of a dive" and preserve your falling velocity to hit the BBEG flying horizontally, because D&D doesn't actually have mechanics for momentum. If you use your fly speed to start moving under your own power, this stops your free fall. There's simply no way to represent the concept of preserving momentum within the very simple movement mechanics of the game. However, as long as there is empty air above the BBEG, you can just use your fly speed to position yourself directly over them and then stop flying (assuming you can do so by e.g. folding up your wings) in order to fall straight down onto them. Even though this involves flying horizontally first and then falling vertically second, if your DM is generous, they might allow you to describe this process as a diving tackle, and they might even allow your momentum to knock the BBEG sideways, perhaps with a strength save to resist or something (which wouldn't happen if you were just falling straight down).
I bring up the idea of the DM allowing this because it is entirely within the intent of the rules for DM to do so if they so choose, even if the rules themselves don't specifically allow for it. As the famous passage from the introduction to the DMG says:

As a referee, the DM acts as a mediator between the rules and the players. A player tells the DM what he or she wants to do, and the DM determines whether it is successful or not, in some cases asking the player to make a die roll to determine success. [...]
The rules don’t account for every possible situation that might arise during a typical D&D session. For example, a player might want his or her character to hurl a brazier full of hot coals into a monster’s face. How you determine the outcome of this action is up to you.

(Note that the "you" in this passage refers to the DM, since this is the DMG.) So I recommend that you ask your DM if they will allow something like this, in addition to asking them whether you will be using the optional rule cited above.

Note: If you expect skydiving to be a regular part of your group's adventuring, your group may also want to refer to the Xanathar's Guide to Everything optional rule for rate of falling, which basically says that you fall 500 feet per round (see the source for details). With this rule, it will actually take you 3 rounds to fall from 1500 feet.

With pulling out of the dive, I was thinking I kind of use my wings from being a fairy to transition from a fall to a glide, using my wings to sort of glide forward. Like, imagine you have a paraglider, and you pull it out, holding it in a way where it doesn't immediately stop you, and then you tilt it back to keep your momentum but in a different direction. Does that make sense?

@Tasi Yes, I understand what you mean. Like I said, there aren't mechanics for momentum, so the idea of "keeping your momentum" simply can't be represented within the rules. The only way to execute a "falling tackle" by RAW is to fall straight down onto someone. Anything else would require the DM to work with you.
